# How get the images signature field in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Maybe someone  can help me, how get the  image signature  field present on Users >> Preference

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show it in a report it's something like this:

```
<img t-if="o.create_uid.signature_logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % o.create_uid.signature_logo"
style="max-height:100px;"/>
```

Otherwise, can you explain better what do you need?